# Align captions center & under the Featurette image in Twitter Bootstrap's Carousel Template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, figure

I'm trying to align a figure caption centered and underneath the `Featurette` images in Twitter Bootstrap's Carousel Template:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

Does anyone know how this can be done and have it still work responsively? I tried adding this HTML:

```
<figure>
  <img class="featurette-image pull-right image-responsive" src="../images/file.jpg">
  <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and this CSS:

```
figure {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

figure img {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}

figcaption {
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
}
```

...to the template's existing code but that wasn't even close. Is there a simple solution to this that works within the Carousel Template's HTML/CSS?

This is the general featurette section HTML:

```
<div class="featurette">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <figure>
        <img class="featurette-image pull-right image-responsive" data-toggle="tooltip" title="title" src="../images/image.jpg">
        <figcaption>test</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>

    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Text: <span class="muted">Text</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">Some text.</p>
  </div>
```

A centered caption under the three large browser icon images to be specific!
    http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

Answer (score 1):

add text-align: center

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/5b3863c2aa84715bec39a06b7b4fa63b/tumblr_mytjrmq67H1rnq2uxo5_400.png" />
  <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
 </figure>



figure {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: center ;
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3cWgJ/1/)

CSS UPDATED:

```
.carousel-caption {
background-color: transparent;
position: static;
max-width: 550px;
padding: 0 20px;
margin-top: 200px;
text-align: center;
margin: 200px auto;
}
```

[image]

this is your solution have fun!

```
<div class="featurette">
    <figure class="row">
         <img class="featurette-image pull-right" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/examples/browser-icon-chrome.png">
         <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h2 class="featurette-heading text-center">First featurette headling. <span class="muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
    <p class="lead text-center">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
</div>
```

[image]

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO SMALL SCREEN](http://jsfiddle.net/4kcFv/)

## [JSFIDDLE FULL SCREEN](http://jsfiddle.net/4kcFv/embedded/result/)

Comment: Not even close, on my Carousel template that aligns the caption center and above the main featurette text...but thanks for trying.

Comment: Your Fiddle is exactly what i want and need. However, within that particular template it doesn't seem to work. Please try to make that same caption under the large featurette images here and tell me I'm not crazy: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

Comment: do you want to center Example headline.(figcaption)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49671/discussion-between-kougiland-and-john-trichereau)

Comment: Kougiland let me know if you're around tomorrow to chat please! I need a bit more help with those stupid featurette images. I wish it were as easy as the carousel ones to add a caption.

Comment: hi i am here let me know when you are on

Comment: I'm on now if you're around

Comment: Bootstrap 3 Carousel is out since a while http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: Yes but I have an entire Rails app, if I upgrade it will take a few days to do... right now I don't need it, will let people iron out the kinks in the TB3 code for a few more months. Btw your fix is nice but not what I was asking for, how can I send you an image?